# Leo columnas de CSV pero al mandarla fuera de la función me da undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, csv

Estoy leyendo con una función un documento CSV, con JavaScript (estoy usando Node.js, Express.js). Este es el código:

```
function dameEamsFromCSV(){
        const fs = require('fs');

        fs.readFile('articulos1.csv', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            //Con el slice ya le digo que sólo me lea a partir del index 1 del array
        var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/).slice(1);
        dataArray.forEach(element=>{
            const row=element.split(';') //Le digo que me separe cada fila por puntos y comas, es decir, ya tengo sólo los eam
            let eam=row[0];
            // console.log(eam);
            return eam; 
        })
    });
}

let eam=dameEamsFromCSV();
console.log(eam);
```

Esto es lo que me saca la pantalla cuando descomento la línea de la función de console.log(eam):

```
1
3
6
8
9
10
```

Eso son los eam, los ID de la tabla de CSV que realmente quiero tener. Ahora lo quiero meter en un array (yo ya leo los datos de un MySQL, lo que no sé es si directamente-sin guardarlos en array-puedo ver directamente por el eam cuáles de los artículos de MySQL están en el CSV) y el problema es que al hacerle el console.log fuera de la función me muestra que es undefined el valor de eam. Entiendo que es un problema de ámbito, pero no sé en qué estoy fallando si precisamente estoy haciendo return eam. Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes bastantes problemas en tu código:

```
function dameEamsFromCSV(){
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile('articulos1.csv', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
```

la función `readFile` es asíncrona, con lo que necesita una función callback que indique qué vamos a hacer con el resultado (el parámetro `data`), o en caso de error (el parámetro `err`)

```
    var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/).slice(1);
```

Aquí simplemente divides el resultado en líneas, sin problema.

```
    dataArray.forEach(element=>{
      const row=element.split(';') //Le digo que me separe cada fila por puntos y comas, es decir, ya tengo sólo los eam
      let eam=row[0];
      // console.log(eam);
      return eam; 
    });
```

El método forEach ejecuta la función que le pases para cada elemento del array. Es decir, realmente ese código es equivalente a:

```
    for (element of dataArray) {
      const row=element.split(';');
      let eam=row[0];
      // return eam;
    }
```

Fíjate en que he comentado el `return`, porque el método `forEach` **ignorará** lo que la función que le pasas devuelva. Y aunque hiciese algo con ese resultado, tu código no está intentando guardarlo. Creo que te has confundido pensando que el `return` es de la función `dameEamsFromCSV()`, pero no es así.
Y aunque fuese así, **`readFromFile` de nuevo ignorará** lo que la función callback devuelva.

```
  });
}

let eam = dameEamsFromCSV();
console.log(eam);
```

Finalmente intentas obtener resultados de tu función, pero realmente tu función no está devolviendo nada.

La forma de trabajar con funciones asíncronas sería la siguiente:

```
function dameEamsFromCSV(hacerAlgoConLosDatosCallBack){
  const fs = require('fs');

  fs.readFile('articulos1.csv', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    const dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/).slice(1);

    // el método map genera un nuevo array con los resultados de la función
    //que le pasas, en este caso sí usa lo que devuelve tu función
      const eams = dataArray.map(element => {
      const row = element.split(';') 
      return row[0];
    });
    //aquí tenemos todos los eams
    hacerAlgoConLosDatosCallBack(eams);
  });
}

dameEamsFromCSV(eams => console.log(eams));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ha ayudado mucho. Algunas preguntas:

-Estoy intentando con el siguiente código quitar el último valor del array, que es un espacio en blanco del CSV. He usado "let noSpacesEams=dameEamsFromCSV.pop();" y tb "let noSpacesEams=dameEamsFromCSV.trim();" pero me dan error los dos y no comprendo por qué. Por otro lado, no comprendo por qué al final, al llamar a la función, le cambias el parámetro. Antes era "dameEamsFromCSV(hacerAlgoConLosDatosCallBack)" y ahora es "dameEamsFromCSV(eams => console.log(eams));". ¿Por qué? Muchas gracias.

Comment: La función `dameEamsFromCSV`no devuelve nada, pero recibe como parámetro una función `hacerAlgoConLosDatosCallBack` que será llamada cuando se tengan los datos, pasándole los mismos como parámetro.

Comment: En mi ejemplo la función que le paso como parámetro es `eams => console.log(eams)`. Es decir, si quieres hacer cualquier cosa con los datos, crea una función que los reciba como parámetro y pasa la función a dameEamsFromCSV